# Pandas distribute time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I have something like the following time series:

```
ts = pd.Series(index=['2017-01-01','2017-01-03', '2017-01-10'], data=[100,200,500])
ts.index=pd.to_datetime(ts.index)

ts
Out[92]: 
2017-01-01    100
2017-01-03    200
2017-01-10    500
dtype: int64
```

I want to distribute the value in each day over the following 4 days. So for example, 100 would be distributed as 20 in each of the dates 2017-01-01, 2017-01-02, 2017-01-03, 2017-01-04, and 2017-01-05.

I can achieve this is follows:

```
days_to_spread_over = 4
results=[]
for datevalue, value in ts.iteritems():
    new = pd.Series(index = pd.date_range(start=datevalue, end = datevalue+timedelta(days=days_to_spread_over), freq='D'),
                    data = [value/float(days_to_spread_over+1)]*(days_to_spread_over+1))
    results.append(new)

f = pd.concat(results).groupby(level=0).sum()
print f

2017-01-01     20.0
2017-01-02     20.0
2017-01-03     60.0
2017-01-04     60.0
2017-01-05     60.0
2017-01-06     40.0
2017-01-07     40.0
2017-01-10    100.0
2017-01-11    100.0
2017-01-12    100.0
2017-01-13    100.0
2017-01-14    100.0
dtype: float64
```

Is there a better way to do this using pandas time series functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimise the computation for the values using division followed by a `np.repeat` call, but computing the date-ranges will require a loop.

Here's a no doubt cleaner way of doing this. First, compute the values of the series, by performing a division, and then repeating it `5` times (number of days to spread over -

```
i = (ts.values / 5).repeat(5)
```

Now, run a loop over each index, calling `pd.date_range` and adding the values to a list `j` -

```
j = []

for x, y in zip(ts.index, ts.index + pd.Timedelta(days=4)):
    j.extend(pd.date_range(x, y))
```

Now, initialise your series, and the perform the `groupby`.

```
pd.Series(i, index=j).groupby(level=0).sum()

2017-01-01     20.0
2017-01-02     20.0
2017-01-03     60.0
2017-01-04     60.0
2017-01-05     60.0
2017-01-06     40.0
2017-01-07     40.0
2017-01-10    100.0
2017-01-11    100.0
2017-01-12    100.0
2017-01-13    100.0
2017-01-14    100.0
dtype: float64
```

---

`i`

```
array([  20.,   20.,   20.,   20.,   20.,   40.,   40.,   40.,   40.,
         40.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.,  100.])
```

`j`

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04',
           '2017-01-05', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05',
           '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-11',
           '2017-01-12', '2017-01-13', '2017-01-14'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will using `apply` + `groupby`

```
df=ts.to_frame('Val').reset_index()
df['index']=df['index'].apply(lambda x : pd.date_range(start=x,periods=5).tolist())
df.Val/=5
ts_new=df.set_index('Val')['index'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().groupby(0).Val.sum()
ts_new
Out[33]: 
0
2017-01-01     20.0
2017-01-02     20.0
2017-01-03     60.0
2017-01-04     60.0
2017-01-05     60.0
2017-01-06     40.0
2017-01-07     40.0
2017-01-10    100.0
2017-01-11    100.0
2017-01-12    100.0
2017-01-13    100.0
2017-01-14    100.0
Name: Val, dtype: float64
```